# How to add automatic Quality selector in javascript videoplayer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can I add automatic/adaptite quality selector option in this video player and how it can also support akamaihd m3u8 link also?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .plyr {
      max-width: 400px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <center>
    <div style="responsive-embed-container">
      <video id="player" class="plyr" controls preload="metadata">
<source src="https://akamaihd123515212121211urlhere.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
    </div>
  </center>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var player = new Plyr(document.getElementById("player"), {});
      player.on("ready", function(event) {
        var instance = event.detail.plyr;
        var hslSource = null;
        var sources = instance.media.querySelectorAll("source"),
          i;
        for (i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
          if (sources[i].src.indexOf(".m3u8") > -1) {
            hslSource = sources[i].src
          }
        }
        if (hslSource !== null && Hls.isSupported()) {
          var hls = new Hls();
          hls.loadSource(hslSource);
          hls.attachMedia(instance.media);
          hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
            console.log("MANIFEST_PARSED")
          })
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is it possible to add these function on this player using only front-end languages.

Comment: If it currently does not support `akamaihd` then why do you believe we can make it support it?`

Comment: @carsten-l%c3%b8vbo-andersen it means not with the code above .. may be with other code hls.js support it

Comment: You will need different source links for all the quality levels you want, and then change the video source according to the selected quality by the user through javascript. You can build it yourself or use some kind of library like https://github.com/sampotts/plyr but you will be needing different sources anyways, unless there is something that automatically creates video sources for all the possible quality levels, but that would need significant effort.

Comment: @abhishek-kumar-tiwari I have master m3u8 which have adaptive quality